# Grid in an R plot

Tags: r, plot

Is there a command to easily add a grid onto an R plot?

Comment: Or better yet, use ggplot2 for plotting. It has lots of really awesome defaults (including grids, which can be customized) and has a very natural and thoughtful grammer for assigning aesthetic attributes to aspects of your plots based on the data you are working with. It's th

Comment: Maybe consider changing accepted answer to [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42729195/680068) ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you are not using a custom tick interval, you can control the grid and axes parameters directly from the `plot()` command:

```
plot(cumsum(rnorm(100)), type='l', panel.first=grid())
```

The `plot.default()` documentation provides more information about these parameters.

Comment: Careful, it does not work if you are using the formula method `plot(x~y, panel.first= grid())`

Comment: `panel.first` argument is lazy-evaluated, it messes up the grid often. Pity.

Comment: This answer is incorrect because it will add grid lines in the tick marks of the default axis. The answer by @cbare should be the one accepted.

Answer (score 60):

The *grid* command seems to draw grid lines where-ever it feels like. I usually use *abline* to put lines exactly where I want them. For example,

```
abline(v=(seq(0,100,25)), col="lightgray", lty="dotted")
abline(h=(seq(0,100,25)), col="lightgray", lty="dotted")
```

Good luck!

Comment: That's fantastic. `grid()` desperately needs arguments for where to place the first grid-line on each axis. This is a great substitute.

Answer (score 47):

See `help(grid)` which works with standard graphics -- short example:

```
R> set.seed(42)
R> plot(cumsum(rnorm(100)), type='l')
R> grid()
```

The [ggplot2](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggplot2) package defaults to showing grids due to its 'Grammar of Graphics' philosophy.  And [lattice](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lattice) has a function `panel.grid()` you can use in custom panel functions.

By the way, there are search functions for help as e.g. `help.search("something")` and there is an entire package called [sos](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sos) to make R web searches more fruitful.

Comment: In cases when we want grid in the background, see [below answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42729195/680068).

Answer (score 5):

I agree with cbare.
Use `abline` to draw lines only where you really need.

Example from my last code:

```
abline(v=c(39448, 39814), col="grey40")
abline(h=c(-0.6, -0.4, -0.2, 0.2,0.4,0.6), col="grey10", lty="dotted")
```

remember that:

`v` is for vertical lines.
`h` for horizontal.

exploit the commands

`lty` for dotted line
`color` for light coloured line

in order to obtain "no heavy grid".

Answer (score 2):

Another option is using the [axis](https://www.statmethods.net/advgraphs/axes.html) function for vertical and horizontal grid lines:

```r
x <- rnorm(100)
plot(x)
# Vertical grid
axis(1, tck = 1, lty = 2, col = "gray")
# Horizontal grid  
axis(2, tck = 1, lty = 2, col = "gray")
```

[image]

```r
# Only vertical grid
plot(x)
# Vertical grid
axis(1, tck = 1, lty = 2, col = "gray")
```

[image]

```r
# Only horizontal grid
plot(x)
# Horizontal grid  
axis(2, tck = 1, lty = 2, col = "gray")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-08-20 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

You can specify the position of the grid lines using the `at` argument.